# Adding a column in table

Tags: tables

I wants to add a column between column 2 and column 3, how can i do that? i'm a beginner in latex. thanks

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}
 \caption{Some optimum Parity Polynomials}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l p{.5cm} p{4cm} p{.5cm} l}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Code Rate & & Constraint\break Length  & & Parity Polynomial \\
    \noalign{\smallskip} 
    \hline
    \noalign{\smallskip} 

        1/2 
        & &
        3
    %   & &
    %   4
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(111)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(101)_2$                  
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
                    1/2 
        & &
        4
        %& &
        %8
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(1011)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(1101)_2$                 
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
        1/2 
        & &
        5           
        %& &
        %16
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(10101)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(11101)_2$                
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
                    1/2 
        & &
        6
                    %& &
        %32
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(101011)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(101101)_2$               
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
                    1/2 
        & &
        7
                    %& &
        %64
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(121)_8$ or $(1001011)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(101)_8$ or $(11100101)_2$               
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
        1/2 
        & &
        8
        %& &
        %128
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(171)_8$ or $(10011011)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(151)_8$ or $(10011001)_2$               
            \\
        }
        \\
        \\
        1/2 
        & &
        9
                %   & &
        %256
        & &
        \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \raggedright
            g\_0 : $(171)_8$ or $(10011011)_2$ \break
            g\_1 : $(151)_8$ or $(10011001)_2$               
            \\
        }
        \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:nlplevels}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you made the rest of your columns...

NOTE: I changed your code a bit.

CODE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Some optimum Parity Polynomials}~\\

\begin{tabular}{cccl}

\toprule
Code Rate & Constraint Length & New Column & Parity Polynomial \\
\midrule

1/2     &   3   &   a   &   g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(111)_2$                 \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(101)_2$                 \\~\\
1/2     &   4   &   c   &   g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(1011)_2$                \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(1101)_2$                \\~\\
1/2     &   5   &   e   &   g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(10101)_2$               \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(11101)_2$               \\~\\
1/2     &   6   &   g   &   g\_0 : $(7)_8$ or $(101011)_2$              \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(5)_8$ or $(101101)_2$              \\~\\
1/2     &   7   &   i   &   g\_0 : $(121)_8$ or $(1001011)_2$           \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(101)_8$ or $(11100101)_2$          \\~\\
1/2     &   8   &   k   &   g\_0 : $(171)_8$ or $(10011011)_2$          \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(151)_8$ or $(10011001)_2$          \\~\\
1/2     &   9   &   m   &   g\_0 : $(171)_8$ or $(10011011)_2$          \\
        &       &       &   g\_1 : $(151)_8$ or $(10011001)_2$          \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

YIELDS:

[image]